# Did `<> ##` ever match `NULL` for some older version of MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, version

There's a `WHERE foo <> ##` clause in a MySQL query that currently is excluding rows where `foo IS NULL`.  The contention is that a listing based off this query **used** to include such rows.  Did the `<> ##` operator ever include `NULL` rows for some past versions of MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing anything to NULL with an operator like `=`, `<`, `>`, `!=`, `<>`, `LIKE`, `IN()`, etc. returns NULL, signifying an unknown boolean state.

This has always been the case in MySQL, as it should be, because ANSI SQL defines NULL semantics that way.

MySQL has an operator `<=>` which can compare NULLs. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to